# selinium selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message

Tags: python, selenium, linkedin-api

Please here here is error message

D:\myPython\ML\venv\Scripts\python.exe D:/myPython/ML/NLP/Linkedin.py

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/myPython/ML/NLP/Linkedin.py", line 42, in <module>
buttonPeople = login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember10458"]/ul/li[1]/button')))
File "D:\myPython\ML\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\support\wait.py", line 80, in until
raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:
```

I tried bothways but none is working.

```
myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember10458"]/ul/li[1]/button') 
and
login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember10458"]/ul/li[1]/button')))
```

Here is my full code

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
myDriver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
login_wait = WebDriverWait(myDriver, 30)
myDriver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/uas/login")
myDriver.maximize_window()
email = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_key-login"]')
email.send_keys('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
time.sleep(2)
password = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="session_password-login"]')
password.send_keys('YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY')
time.sleep(2)
login = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-primary"]')
login.click()
time.sleep(2)
search = login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember1135"]/input')))
search.send_keys("python programmer")
button = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="nav-search-controls-wormhole"]/button')
button.click()


# buttonPeople = myDriver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember10458"]/ul/li[1]/button')
buttonPeople = login_wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="ember10458"]/ul/li[1]/button')))
buttonPeople.click()
```

Comment: Id attributes are dynamic. Try `//*[starts-with(@id, "ember")]/ul/li[1]/button`

Comment: It worked , many thanks .......Can you explain me your code , please

Comment: `starts-with(@id, "ember")` allows to select node by *static* part of `id` - `"ember"` and skip dynamic part - `"10458"`

Comment: u r awsome man . many thanks for help